# android adjustresize adjustpan famous issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm not looking for code, either I won't post any, just an explanation, because I'm kind of lost.

There is this main issue about the resizing when softkeyboard appear.

**In my case**

I have a listView feeded with 2 editText and many textView with database content using a custom cursorAdapter.

1) AdjustPan

It's pretty simple. When I use the adjustPan property, everything works quite good, except the fact that when I press an editText in my listView and if the listview is bigger than the screensize, I can't scroll. This is actually the normal behaviour and I can understand it.

2) AdjustResize

Here I can scroll as much as I wish.

This property is the one I want to use. But I'm facing 2 issues :

- When I press on one of the two editText, I just can't write in. Impossible, even thought it has the focus. I'm forcing the softkeyboard to appear, I try to type some letters in (remember that this editText is focused) but nothing happens.
- Again, when I press one of the two editText, it just reorganize (apparently randomly) listview's items. Even thought it's working perfectly with adjustPan, with adjustResize, it's messing with items of the listView.

Any information about one of the 2 issues would be helpful. You can even ask for code, but one more time, I'm just looking for a general explanation that could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here this mention issue is same facing me in my app and here some change in my code is this working fine in my app. please try this...

```
<activity android:name="com.MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fields_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        />


 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```